# How to add table headers to dynamically generated table containing Ajax data?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I am attempting to dynamically add the table header from the `JSON` data.
I need to generate the header (`th`) as well so that it is not done manually.

I have a very basic working example: And I am familiar with the `JQuery` solution, however, I would like to do this in a JavaScript only approach:

Some JSON formatted data:

```
var value = [{
    "City": "KABUL",
        "Continent": "ASIA",
        "Country": "AFGHANISTAN",
        "CountryAbbr": "AF",
        "CountryId": "102120"
}, {
    "City": "MARIEHAMN",
        "Continent": "EUROPE",
        "Country": "ALAND ISLANDS",
        "CountryAbbr": "AX",
        "CountryId": "102115"
}];
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var out = "<table>";

for ( var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    out += "<tr><td>" + value[i].Country +
        "</td><td>" + value[i].City +
        "</td><td>" + value[i].CountryAbbr +
        "</td></tr>";
}
out += "</table>";

document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = out;
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

A working fiddle:
[dynamically generated table containing Ajax data](https://jsfiddle.net/2objjecj/2/)

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Presumably you have tried adding <tr><th>header 1</th></tr>?

Comment: I need to generate the headers as well. So `Country, City, CountryAbbr.`
I am not certain how to get the data and the header.

Comment: You can do it dynamically, but since you've hardcode the values you want, what's the point of heaving the header dynamic?

You already know that you just need to add <tr><th>Country</th> ...</tr>.
If you want to chose dynamically which columns to show\hide, then you should build both the headers and the value cells dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about table header/heading.then the below code is helpful to you:

```
var value = [{
    "City": "KABUL",
        "Continent": "ASIA",
        "Country": "AFGHANISTAN",
        "CountryAbbr": "AF",
        "CountryId": "102120"
}, {
    "City": "MARIEHAMN",
        "Continent": "EUROPE",
        "Country": "ALAND ISLANDS",
        "CountryAbbr": "AX",
        "CountryId": "102115"
}];

var out = "<table>";
out+="<tr><th>Country</th><th>City</th><th>Country Code</th></tr>";//TABLE HEADER/HEADING----------
for ( var i = 0; i < value.length; i++ ) {
    out += "<tr><td>" + value[i].Country +
        "</td><td>" + value[i].City +
        "</td><td>" + value[i].CountryAbbr +
        "</td></tr>";
}
out += "</table>";

document.getElementById("tableContainer").innerHTML = out;
```

[image: Here is the snapshot of your jsfiddle]

Comment: Thanks!
This is great but I am going to see how I can generate all of the HTML dynamically instead of hard coding the values or tags. Another question.

Comment: Ok...then you can use the JSON result key (Continent,Country,CountryAbbr,CountryId)as header/title dynamically just before the for loop.